# RTK Query hook: why data triggering each UI actions?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

In my component I am using rtk query hook and using `data` to pass it as options to my MUI Autocomplete component, BUT when I selected option, it doesn't applies, because on click actions `data` triggers again and passing again to options list of Autocomplete component.
Why `data` triggering each time when I did any actions in page? Request sending each time and `data` triggers each time? Why? How I can fix this issue?

```
interface IProps {
    label?: string;
    onChange?: (value: IBranchDto | null) => void;
}

export const ApBranchAutocomplete = ({label, onChange}: IProps) => {
    const id = useId();

    const [getData, {data, isLoading}] = useLazyGetBranchAllQuery();

    useEffect(() => {
        getData();
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("data");
    }, [data]);

    const handleChange = (_e: React.SyntheticEvent<Element, Event>, value: IBranchDto | null) => {
        onChange?.(value);
    };

    return (
        <>
            <Autocomplete
                autoComplete
                disablePortal
                id={id}
                options={data ?? []}
                onChange={handleChange}
                getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name ?? ""}
                isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option.id === value.id}
                sx={{width: 300}}
                renderInput={(params) => (
                    <TextField
                        {...params}
                        InputProps={{
                            ...params.InputProps,
                            endAdornment: (
                                <>
                                    {isLoading ? <CircularProgress color="inherit" size={20} /> : null}
                                    {params.InputProps.endAdornment}
                                </>
                            ),
                        }}
                        label={label}
                    />
                )}
                loading={isLoading}
                size="small"
            />
        </>
    );
};
```

I am using this component in parent page like that:

```
const onBranchChange = (value: IBranchDto | null) => {
    if (value) setBranchId(value.id);
};
...

        <StyledFormControl size="small">
            <FormLabel sx={{fontSize: "0.8125rem", color: "var(--neutral-70)", mb: "0.5rem", textTransform: "uppercase"}}>
                Branch
            </FormLabel>
            <ApBranchAutocomplete onChange={onBranchChange} />
        </StyledFormControl>
```

Packages version:

```
"@mui/material": "^5.14.4",
"@mui/styled-engine-sc": "^5.12.0",
"react-redux": "^8.1.2",
"@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
"styled-components": "^5.3.11",
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
```

Comment: Seems this `ApBranchAutocomplete` component is remounting if the `useEffect` and `getData` are being continually called. What is rendering `ApBranchAutocomplete`? Can you [edit] to provide a more complete [mcve] so we can see all the code is doing and when/why?